# How can I change the system language to German - even if the system won't change the language

Tags: 12.04, language-support

Yesterday, I have updated my Ubuntu 12.04 installation. After a restart, Ubuntu chose Chinese or some similar as default language. So, all my menus/windows are a mix of English and Chinese. Previously, I had the German language active.

I was able to re-order the language within the language-support. German is now my first option, followed by English and - maybe - Chinese. But now, my system is a mix of English (for the activity screen and the most programs like Firefox) and Germen (only for some the left panel of the gnome-tweak-tool).

In `All Settings` >> `User Accounts` I have selected `German` for the language.

It seems, that Ubuntu ignores all my language settings - it's still in English. I have also tried, to re-install the language packs, but with no success.

Any suggestions, to bring my desktop back to the German language?

Comment: Did you apply German System Wide?

Comment: I would like to see the content of the following files: `~/.profile`, `/etc/default/locale`, `/etc/environment`, `~/.dmrc`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I tried this:

1. Go to "**System Settings**" -->   "**Keyboard **Layout**"
   (in German it is "**Systemeinstellungen**" --> "**Tasten**"
2. Add the "**English**" keyboard layout to the list. Now there will appear a keyboard-symbol in the menu-bar beneath your name, etc.
3. Click at that symbol and select "**German**".